# VBA Excel 2007 macro dies in Excel 2002

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2002, vba

I have just tried to send a workbook to a friend that has a chart with a drop-down box on it. In excel 2007 I have used:

`If Chart2.Shapes(2).ControlFormat.ListCount = "16" Then`

To check the size of the list so that it doesnt get entered in again (resulting in an extremely long list that repeats itself). This line works well in Excel 2007, but gives a `Object doesn't support this property or method.` error in Excel 2002.

What is the difference between working with shapes in 2002 vs 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it ended up being something simple that took me ages to pick up on.

Excel 2007 counts shapes differently to 2002. The shape I was trying to reference in 2007 `(2)` was now `(1)` in 2002.

So, the final result was of course

`If Chart2.Shapes(1).ControlFormat.ListCount = "16" Then`

Comment: btw what does checking if listcount=16 do? Sorry if this is a bit of noob question.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is you don't get to use the shiny new methods and collections introduced over the years. Unfortunately [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726438%28v=office.12%29.aspx) isn't going to be much help to you in this area. Your best bet is to somehow pick up the [appropriate help file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222101) and read the documentation for the version you want. You can find all the 2002 help files [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=34B793A2-934E-44E5-8C4A-5E06F683FF63&displaylang=EN).

The problem you are facing is that the ListCount property is read only in 2002.